# phpMyAdmin 2-factor authentication, can't see Authenticator App as an option

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

After a fair bit of doing, I finally got phpMyAdmin to allow 2FA. Unfortunately, it's only giving me two options: None and Hardware, whereas I want to be able to scan a QR code and use an Authenticator app (Google Authenticator, Authy, etc).

According to [the documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/two_factor.html) it's totally possible. I ran the composer lines:

```
composer require pragmarx/google2fa
composer require bacon/bacon-qr-code
composer require samyoul/u2f-php-server
composer require pragmarx/google2fa-qrcode
```

... and copied them into the appropriate place in phpMyAdmin, changed up the autoload to include everything.... But no option for authenticator app appears. Anyone know why and how to fix it? I've combed through the configuration file and come up empty handed.

[Screenshot of phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTkPa.png)

phpMyAdmin version 4.9.0.1 from the remi repository on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **phpMyAdmin** RPM package, you don't have to play with composer, simply install the optional dependencies (which are automatically pulled, by default, on Fedora and RHEL 8)

```
yum install php-pragmarx-google2fa php-bacon-qr-code php-samyoul-u2f-php-server
```

Then, after having configured the "database storage", the 2 auth factor will appear, when conected, in the parameters page, for the user.

Comment: Did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: As long as I have the attention of "the" Remi, a question for you, if I may... Right now, I always install stuff with --enablerepo=remi,remi-php73. Should I be defaulting these repos to "on" or only calling them when I need them like this?

Comment: Yes, especially, as remi-php73 only provides PHP, nothing else, and as explained by the Wizard, see https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ ("remi" is usually not needed, dependencies are in "remi-safe")

Comment: I've installed all of the above, but phpMyAdmin isn't showing the option for TOTP anymore. I think it's been since phpMyAdmin updated.  5.5.53-log - Source distribution. Any idea?